# Output terabytes of data in hive external table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql, hadoop2

I have terabytes of data which is already processed and compressed in the table. Now i want to dump the data in Hive External Table without compressing the put file. Can we put the data in chunks in the external table or is there is any optimized way of doing this. If i do it in one go it takes terabytes of space and i want to optimize on that part.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE <table name>
(uuid STRING, t1 STRING, t2 STRING) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
LOCATION '${OUTPUT}';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE <table name> SELECT uuid, t1, t2 from <table name>;
```

Please suggest. It always ran out of hdfs memory.

NOTE: If i enable compression then i don't find any issue.
set mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec; 
set mapred.output.compress=true; 
set hive.exec.compress.output=true; 
set 
mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;

Comment: The post does not make sense.

Comment: where you have your terabytes of data and which table it is stored. Please specify? Anyways you have to read some hdfs and hive documents, as may be because of insufficient knowledge and lack of clarity this question is creating confusion.